# How do you display pivot table data in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, view, model, controller

I have more stations in one city and I want to use the `station_city_id` to show the `city_name` form the second table

```html
<tbody>

    @foreach ($station as $stations )

        <tr>

            <th scope="row">{{ $stations->station_name }}</th>
```

This is where I want the city name from a different database and I dont want to hardcode it

```html
                {{ $city_name }}

            </td>

            <td>{{ $stations->station_phone_1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $stations->station_phone_2 }}</td>

        </tr>

    @endforeach

</tbody
```

Comment: Do you mean different `table` or `database`? & is `city_name` related with `station`?

Comment: i have 2 tables stations and cities, and i put in stations the station_city_id wich is the same as the city_id in cities.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships)

Database scheme tables with respective ids:

- cities
- stations
- city_station

Define the relationships in each model

Cities.php model

```
public function stations()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Stations');
}
```

Stations.php model

```
public function city()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Cities');
}
```

Controller

```
//$id = City id
public function view_cities_stations($id) {
  $city = Cities::find($id);

  return view('view', compact('city'));
}
```

Blade view

```
@foreach($city->stations as $station)
  {{$station->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I still don't understand how this works in the controller part. How do i get the city id in the function?  my model is called City.php , the table name is cities and the column name i need is city_name.

Comment: In your routes web.php do you have a route for /cities/{id} using CitiesController? In the console type php artisan route:list and add that output to your question.

Comment: I don't have that route, I want to show all stations with the city where the station is. The route name /location in the controller and i want to use it to show everything in it,is that possible?

Comment: Create the route: route::get('/locations/{id}', 'LocationController@show');

Comment: Thank you,you helped me to start using relatioships, I found a little different solution without the new route.  and i can display the city name by just using {{ $stations->city->city_name }}

Comment: Exactly! Great job